# Download multiple files from GOOGLE CLOUD STORAGE BUCKET

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage

Does anyone know how to pull all the data for a file that start with a 'Test' in a GCS bucket? I have tried to use the glob.glob method and wildcard `glob.glob('*.csv')` and that has not worked! Any help would be much appreciated.

```
from google.cloud import storage

def download_blob(bucket_name, source_blob_name, destination_file_name):
    
  bucket_name = 'gcs-bucket'
  source_blob_name = 'folder1/folder2/Test_data_01052022104530.csv'
  destination_file_name = r'C:\Users\path\path1\path2\path3\path4\Test.csv'
  storage_client = storage.Client()
  bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)
  blob = bucket.blob(source_blob_name)
  blob.download_to_filename(destination_file_name)
```

Comment: When listing files, you can set the `prefix` to `Test`. All objects that start with those characters will be returned. I am not sure what you are referring to with `glob`. The API does not have a `glob` feature and you do not show that in your code.

Comment: and where do i set the prefix?

Comment: Please search the documentation first. For example https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/samples/storage-list-files-with-prefix

Answer (score 0):

GCS doesn't have the concept of directories, so "folder1/folder2/Test_data_01052022104530.csv" is not a file called "Test_data_01052022104530.csv", but an object called "folder1/folder2/Test_data_01052022104530.csv". So you don't want to look for files starting "Test", but objects with the string "/Test" anywhere in their name (or that start with "Test", for the root").

GCS provides no facility to do this, you will have to list objects and filter to do it. For example:

```py
  client = storage.Client()
  for blob in client.list_blobs(BUCKET):
    if "/Test" in blob.name or blob.name.startswith("Test"):
      blob.download_to_filename(somewhere)
```

For large buckets, this might be slow, especially if there are few files that match. Some ways to speed it up:

- If your data is structured so that you have a small number of directories, and a small fraction of the files will match: it may be faster to "walk the tree" using the prefix and delimiter options of list_blobs and then for each "directory" do a list_blobs with prefix `directory+"/Test"` to list matching objects only.
- Do listing or downloads in parallel